# using len in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the city with the highest character count in a dataset.

But I am getting this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near 'len'

I am not sure why, as when I replace `max len(city)` with the appropriate number it seems to work.

(I am aware this can be achieved using sort by but I want to understand why I can not achieve this using a where clause)

```
select city 
from station
where len(city) = max len(city)
```

Comment: The syntax error is because `max` requires parentheses: `max(len(city))`. (If you fix that, you'll get a different error.)

Comment: why would i get a different error after fixing the parentheses ?

Comment: Because it's semantically wrong. In each row, `len(city)` is a single value. You can't take the maximum of a single value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression

```
max len(city)
```

is not syntactically correct.
You must replace it with the subquery that get the max length:

```
select city 
from station
where len(city) = (select max(len(city)) from station)
```

Comment: Why would len(city) on the left of our = , syntactically correct yet something similar on the left would not be?

Comment: @KvothesLute The syntax error is `max` (without parentheses), not `len`.

Comment: @KvothesLute `max(len(city))` on its own is not an expression that returns the maximum length. You need a subquery like my code.

Answer (score 0):

I like to write this as:

```
select top (1) with ties city 
from station
order by len(city) desc;
```

Comment: could you explain it?